# Why are Microsoft Windows 8.1 sample apps not compatible with Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Any one have any idea why Microsoft's sample Windows 8.1 apps are not compatible with Visual Studio Express 2013? I get an error telling me that the project is not compatible with this version of Visual Studio - did I miss something, are these sample apps not compatible with the Express version?

Comment: If it tells you that the project isn't compatible then it simply isn't compatible with your Express edition.  There are several, the choice matters.  Avoid forcing us to guess at which sample and which edition you use.

Comment: I guess there must be different versions of VS and different versions of sample apps - never realised that, will investigate...  Thanks